# Environment.DIRECTORY_RECORDINGS pointing to a non-existing folder

Tags: java, android, cordova, mediastore

I am trying to write an Android audio recorder application. I will be using the MediaStore to store the recordings. I would presume that I should store them in the folder pointed to by the Environment.DIRECTORY_RECORDINGS constant... but the folder (whose name should be "Recordings") does not exist on any of the Android devices I tried, and the MediaStore insert operation fails. What is the proper way to create it?

Prior to Android 10, I could request the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and simply create the folder. But what should I do on Android 10 and above?

Comment: The write operation fails? I would think the insert() operation fails.

Comment: Yes, you are right of course, I meant the insert operation.